# The program on xamarin forms is installed on android, but does not start

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

made a trial program on xamarin forms, debugged everything, through debugging via usb everything worked fine, made an apk, through publish, everything is as it should. The apk is installed, but the open button is not pressed, the application is not shown in the menu, it is in the list of all installed applications, but there it has a gray (inactive) pause button. I just started writing in Xamarin and this is the first application, there is definitely no error in the code itself, the code is simple, something is visible in the settings. Tell me what could be wrong? Android 9, minimum version indicated 7. Work in VS 2019.

I've tried setting the target version to 9, but the SDK says 10 is the minimum. Tried reinstalling and rebooting the phone.

Comment: have you checked the device logs or looked at the logs in VS?

Comment: 1. Uninstall the app first, check if you can run the app by installing from the apk. 2. Uninstall, and then check the app you publish is visible from Google store, and if it can be installed. 3. Check if any warnings or errors from Google developer online console.

Answer (score 0):

seems to have solved the problem, for those who stumble upon the same, I changed the assembly name from App5 to App5.Android in the app.Android properties in the Application tab and everything began to work fine